# How to Create Two Amount Columns Based on Specific Categorical Column Values in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, rows

I'm relatively new to R and I have a dataframe that looks like this:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Max | Max | Max | Joey | Joey | Nancy | Nancy | Nancy | Linda | Linda |
| Amount_Type | InternetBill | Groceries | WaterBill | InternetBill | Groceries | WaterBill | Groceries | InternetBill | WaterBill | Groceries |
| Amount | $75 | $230.66 | $40 | $70 | $188.75 | $35 | $175.89 | $75 | $30 | $236.87 |

I need to add 3 more rows and pivot the dataframe:

The dataframe needs to be grouped by name and outputs 3 totals columns:

1. Fixed_Cost which should include InternetBill and WaterBill amounts
2. Variable_Cost which should include Groceries
3. Total_Cost which should be fixed + variable costs

So something like this:

| Name | Fixed_Cost | Variable_Cost | Total_Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Max | $115 | $230.66 | $345.66 |
| Joey | $70 | $188.75 | $258.75 |
| Nancy | $110 | $175.89 | $285.89 |
| Linda | $30 | $236.87 | $266.87 |

Any advice on how to go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we `transpose` the data, it becomes more easier to do a group by `sum`

```
library(data.table)
data.table::transpose(setDT(df1), make.names = 1)[, 
  Amount := readr::parse_number(Amount)][, 
 .(Fixed_Cost = sum(Amount[Amount_Type %in% c("InternetBill", "WaterBill")]), 
 Variable_Cost =  sum(Amount[!Amount_Type %in% c("InternetBill", "WaterBill")])),
       by = Name][,
   Total_Cost := Fixed_Cost + Variable_Cost][]
```

-output

```
     Name Fixed_Cost Variable_Cost Total_Cost
   <char>      <num>         <num>      <num>
1:    Max        115        230.66     345.66
2:   Joey         70        188.75     258.75
3:  Nancy        110        175.89     285.89
4:  Linda         30        236.87     266.87
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`0` = c("Name", "Amount_Type", "Amount"), `1` = c("Max", 
"InternetBill", "$75"), `2` = c("Max", "Groceries", "$230.66"
), `3` = c("Max", "WaterBill", "$40"), `4` = c("Joey", "InternetBill", 
"$70"), `5` = c("Joey", "Groceries", "$188.75"), `6` = c("Nancy", 
"WaterBill", "$35"), `7` = c("Nancy", "Groceries", "$175.89"), 
    `8` = c("Nancy", "InternetBill", "$75"), `9` = c("Linda", 
    "WaterBill", "$30"), `10` = c("Linda", "Groceries", "$236.87"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)   

setNames(data.frame(t(df1[,-1])), df1[,1]) %>%
  pivot_wider(Name, names_from = Amount_Type, values_from = Amount,
              values_fn = parse_number, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Fixed_cost = InternetBill + WaterBill, variable_cost = Groceries,
         Total_Cost = Fixed_cost + variable_cost, .keep ='unused')

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Name  Fixed_cost variable_cost Total_Cost
  <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Max          115          231.       346.
2 Joey          70          189.       259.
3 Nancy        110          176.       286.
4 Linda         30          237.       267.
```

Comment: When I do this it says "Amount_Type" does not exist can't subset columns that don't exist - any advice on how to fix this error? When I look at just this line of code: setNames(data.frame(t(df1[,-1])), df1[,1])  ; the dataframe it produces has the column names Max | 115 | 231 | 346 and not the names of the actual columns

Comment: @Elena seems that your original dataframe does not have the 0th column as presented in the example above. What do you get when you run `df1[,1]`?